# what is webServiceURL and authenticationToken in pass.json and how to it will work with webservice?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, passbook

I have created a one pass it is actually work in ios and walletpasses app for android.

One problem is that we need to communicate with pass to update pass detail.

We have windows server and we want to communicate with pass which is inside apple wallet.

I have read many article and found that we need to specify our web api url inside webserviceurl but i don't know how it manage and how our api structure is for pass.

authenticationToken is key where we need to check inside a api for security purpose but how it will checked inside webservice

so i need some reference that how i can create webapi for passbook using c# and what is a structure of that?

Answer (score 0):

We implemented this at [PassNinja](http://passninja.com). You have to conform to the web service API described in the [Working with Passes section of the Wallet Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1). There is also [further instructions here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html).

> 1. A pass that supports updates is installed, and the user’s device registers with your server to get updates.
> 2. Some change triggers an update, and your server sends a push notification.
> 3. The user’s device receives the notification, and it queries your server to get a list of changes.
> 4. The user’s device asks your server for the latest version of each pass that has changed.

Comment: It is working with NFC but i dont want it i want to communicate through QR Code only. I have read all the documentation i just want reference about Webapi that how it work in background

Comment: The reference docs for the web api are in the links in my answer. What is unclear in the docs that you would like more information about?